# Tips on bulk/batch producing 3D product models with labels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, modeling, adobe-dimension

I want to make a lot of "product photos" by making a 3D model with a label and then rendering it. I know the basics of making a 3D model in Photoshop and rendering it Dimension with a decal/label to make a "product photo", but I have no idea how to efficiently scale that to dozens. And yet I see so many product catalogues with 3D looking mock-ups of their (for example) supplement packaging.

I'm looking for tips on how to do that efficiently. Maybe I have to use a totally different program (I saw that Blender is an option), but what I would like to know is not how to make one but many 3D mock-ups, each based on the same object but with a different label.

Example of a product mock-up with a label:
[image: Example of a product mockup with a label.]

Comment: If you choose to go the Photoshop smart object/mockup route, I would suggest trying my [Batch Mockup Smart Object Replacement script](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Batch-Mockup-Smart-Object-Replacement-photoshop-script) for Photoshop. It's a hassle making mockup files yourself in some cases, like here where there's some curvature... but if you can manage to get the mockups ready, the script can process multiple mockup files, multiple input files, and multiple smart objects per mockup. You might be able to do it without having to do any prep work on the input files (which would be the labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is. Most if not all consumer products allready have 3D models due to them being designed in a 3D CAD application in the first place. Hardly any die, mold, stamp etc has been made without a 3D model for the past 20 to 30 years.

So companies like IKEA are allready doing nearly all of their catalogs digitally. Yes most of the things you think of as photos are renders. Mainly because its cheaper and less timeconsuming to do so. Note that the price to do a picture isnt really affected, the graphic design, the rendering still take a lot of work to do right about the same number of people as a photoshoot. But the digital realm disposes the logistical hurdles of getting the furniture, set designers, photographs, models and support personel into the same space at the same time.

Also if you take the image you have as an example.

- All you really need to do is render the bottle and slap the label as a texture.
- Since 3D DCC tools (graphics programs not CADs for manufacturing) are animation software. All you really need is to animate the texture.
- And drop it to your renderfarm for final rendering. (Since they are animation tools theres literally a button for this)

But yes you could to this in photoshop too. Just make the label a smart object. Wrap overlay and animate the smart object. But... Lot more work than using a 3D app.

All of this is less work than designing the labels.